# Exclude propertie with condition NestJs

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm, class-transformer

I would like to exclude my users' emails when replying to a Public route so as not to reveal them. However, I also need to grab them from my other routes that include a bearer JWT authentication system.
I would like to have a code similar to this:

```
  @Column()
  @Exclude()
  password: string;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  @ExcludeIfPublic()
  email: string;
```

---

Here is my Public decorator:

```
import { SetMetadata } from '@nestjs/common';

export const IS_PUBLIC_KEY = 'isPublic';
export const Public = () => SetMetadata(IS_PUBLIC_KEY, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [use groups to control excluded properties](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#using-groups-to-control-excluded-properties)

```
@Column()
@Exclude()
password: string;

@Column({ unique: true })
@Expose({ groups: ['private'] })
email: string;

// Controller
@SerializeOptions({ groups: ['public'] })
@Get('public-api')
async publicAPI() { ... }

@SerializeOptions({ groups: ['private'] })
@Get('private-api')
async privateAPI() { ... }
```